# Recurring Memory Issues

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, memory, windows-server

We have a Windows Server 2008R2 server with 32GB or RAM running SQL Server 2008R2, along with an IIS server. The machine is also used as a backup server.

The problem is, periodically (every week or two) the SQL takes up all the memory, literally all of it: *resmon* shows 0MB available. Now, I did look the problem up, and I know SQL is *supposed* to take up the entire memory, but it really hurts the web performance, and in the end the SQL itself starts stuttering; scheduled jobs don't execute (the logs say "insufficient resources") etc.

I tried limiting the max memory size to 4096MB. The memory footprint dropped - and rose again to full in a week. 
I tried scheduling a job that would empty the caches every night. Is that likely to help? 
If not, what will?

**edit** Last time it crashed, already after I limited it to 4GB, I wasn't on-site, unfortunately. But the SQL Server logs show the available page file space dropping below 4MB, and the Windows logs report low virtual memory conditions for hours, with sqlservr.exe consuming the most memory (though only about 1,640,919,040 bytes, for some reason).

Comment: How do you know SQL Server process is taking up all the memory?

Comment: Where exactly are you measuring "rose again to full"? After you changed max server memory to 4 GB (you should really change this to 28 or 29 GB, though, since SQL Server clearly does want to use a lot of memory), did you restart the server?

Comment: Emptying the caches every night is almost certainly *not* going to help. SQL Server is just going to populate them again when the data is requested, and for this the application will have to wait. This is like shrinking your log file every night, knowing it's going to grow again tomorrow. What was the point?

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: I measured it in resmon. Right after I changed it to 4GB, the the memory footprint dropped dramatically from 100MB free to more than 10GB even without restarting the server (though we have restatted it since).

Comment: I'd be curious to see the top consumers of private bytes for this machine.  That can be done with PowerShell: `Get-Process | Sort-Object PrivateMemorySize64 -Descending | Select-Object ProcessName, PrivateMemorySize64 -First 10`

Comment: Sqlservr: 4846120960. ReportingServicesService: 425914368. MsDtsSrvr: 266752000. Mcshield: 128110592. Msmdsrv: 95117312. Lsass: 60276736. Powershell: 57548800. Svchost: 56258560. Explorer: 41775104. FireSvc: 36696064.

Comment: The "free bytes" counters mean exactly nothing because the Windows file cache will consume everything that is unused. That's a good thing.; SQL Server's memory usage is neither visible in task manager nor in the private bytes counter. There is no OS-level counter that I know of that accurately shows its memory usage.

Comment: usr is right about the "free bytes" counter, but the PrivateMemory-Counter is valid although it will not match the "Max Memory" exactly as this does not cover the size of the executable for example which the PrivateMemory does. The only case the PrivateMemory is not telling the whole story is when using AWE and 32 bit Windows & SQL.

Comment: Regarding the crash: Any chance that the server is a VM? A lot of "funny" things can happen when the Host is not able to actually satify the memory requirements of the VMs. This becomes more likely to happen when you add a database to the mix, although usually you will get very very bad performance from the database first.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. Thank you. But even if the counters lie (or don't mean what I think they mean), the machine does hang and experience memory shortage. The server is physical, not a VM.

Comment: @user22610 this is new to me. I have here a SQL Server with 8GB buffer pool (in use) on Win7 64 and none of the counters shows a remotely plausible value. Is the counter reliable for you?

Comment: @Alda my theory would be that something else is consuming lots of memory. Maybe in a spiking pattern so that it is hard to catch. Older Windows'es were also prone to page everything out to serve the file cache. After a big file copy everything was paged out. I believe that is gone since Vista.

Comment: Use Sysinternals RAMMap and post a screenshot (ideally, when the condition happens). RAMMap accounts for absolutely everything. Also, use all the memory counters of Process Explorer and post a screenshot. They are all the counters that are available AFAIK.

Comment: @usr, I can't post screenshots. The server is on a closed network. I'm not sure I could catch it in action, but I'll try... also, are RAMMap and Process Explorer available out-of-the-box in Windows Server 2008? There might be a problem getting them from the Web.

Comment: Not out of the box, but they are Microsoft tools if that helps. RAMMap would be especially valuable because it details what the physical memory pages are used for (file cache, private bytes, ...). If we spot something suspicious there that would be good. Does the problem occur at random times? Unpredictable?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds a lot like a problem I have experienced before at a client who was also running IIS and SQL Server 2008 R2 on the same server. The problem would also start with reports of very bad web performance and then slowly grind to a complete halt.

After many hours of trouble shooting we managed to attribute it to a single SQL Server setting found under the "Processors" heading in the Server Properties dialog:

[image: Boost SQL Priority]

When this setting was enabled we constantly experienced the degradation in performance. Although this setting is related to CPU resources we also observed increased memory usage on the server as you explained. It looked as if when this setting was enabled SQL became so hungry for resources that IIS was unable to allocate the resources needed to serve the incoming requests and this in turn caused a backlog of SQL operations which in turn made SQL want to consume more resources and so on and so forth. I have no empirical evidence to back up these claims but this was the observed behavior at the time.

I realize correlation does not equal causation, but we were able to confidently replicate and subsequently mitigate the issue on multiple servers by switching the setting on and off.

After seeing this repeated at a few clients we adopted the policy to have this setting switched of at all clients and we went so far as to report on any changes made to this setting. Suffice to say we have since then not yet experienced issues of this nature again.

I am not saying this is definitely the solution to your problem but given the similarities between the issues you experienced and the ours I would recommend you try it as a first resort since it is very easy to attempt.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I'll try that. Thank you.